# Prevent div with dynamic content overlapping other divs

Tags: html, css

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/m8o21nrb/)

This is the div structure

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="mainG mainGT">
        <div class="rawV">
            <div class="svs"></div>
            <div class="drgM"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="botttom">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

The height of the `.wrapper` is dynamic (I've used `.wrapper{height: 30px;}` as an example in the fiddle). As you can see `.wrapper` is overlapping `.botttom`. How do I prevent `.wrapper` overlapping `.botttom and have`.botttom`below`.wrapper` at all times?

```
|------------|
|  .wrapper  |
|------------|

|------------|
|  .bottom   |
|------------|
```

Comment: Why are you setting a height that doesn't match the contents? Removing that seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Remove the height and it works in the fiddle

Comment: @Isherwood thanks. :) That height is based on the screen height and it's used to place certain elements within the div. Height needs to be there.

Comment: @Andrew thanks. Height needs to specified. How can I fit the wrapper height to its contents?

Comment: Your SVG height is 100px. so you shouldnt be placing a height on the wrapper unless you make it greater than the svg height

Comment: @Andrew. thanks again. ah ha... I just realised the exact issue here. The `wrapper` resizes to fit the svg. So is there a way to avoid the svg over lapping `.bottom`? something like `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` or `display: block;`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `min-height` instead of `height` this will solve your issue.

```
.wrapper
{
min-height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks... looks good. let me try your solution in my project.

Comment: thanks +10 . Have a look https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/m8o21nrb/4/ How can I keep the "Click Me 1" at the bottom of the `.outerWrapper` and make the `.wrapper` fill up to the "Click Me 1" button?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to understand what you're trying to achive ?